# Добавить класс "active" в тег <a> при изменении url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет! 
Как добавить класс "active" в тег "a" при смене адреса?
Ссылки такого формата

```html
<div id="nav-side">
  <a href="http://site.com/one-page/second-page/">Second Page</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `.addClass('active')` должен работать

Comment: @splash58 конечно, а как это сделать при смене адреса? Соотнести строку в браузере и href.

Comment: что значит смена адреса, не пользователь же его меняет, а какая-то функция. в ней и меняйте.

Comment: @splash58 пользователь вручную в адресной строке прописывает "http://site.com/one-page/second-page/", попадает на эту страницу, в меню навигации у "a", у которого href равен значению в адресной строке добавляется класс "active"

Comment: я не сразу понял вопрос :) ну, конечно, при загрузке странице сравните все a.href c location.href . и добавьте

Comment: @splash58 а у вас есть пример функции? было бы супер увидеть ее в ответе сразу)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  let loc = 'http://site.com/one-page/second-page/', // = window.location.href;
    $a = $('#nav-side a');
  $a.each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == loc) $(this).addClass('active');
  });
  console.log(loc);
})
```

```css
a{float:left;clear:both}
.active{color:darkgreen;font-weight:700}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav-side">
  <a href="http://site.com/one-page/perviy-page/">Perviy Page</a>
  <a href="http://site.com/one-page/second-page/">Second Page</a>
</div>
```